# como obtener un variable de otro archivo js

Tags: javascript

tengo el siguiente problema: estoy trabajando con varios archivos **javaScript** y quiero recuperar el contenido de la variable que se genera en otro archivo js.. ejemplo en el archivo1.js se ejecuta y en una función que ahí se encuentra se genera el  valor para una variable que se encuentra declarada al principio del js pero en el archivo2.js después de que se ejecute el archivo1. en el archivo2.js necesito obtener el valor q se genera en el archivo1.js, cabe mencionar que los scripts están linkiados en la pagina principal pero no he podido recupera ese valor me marca vacío o indefinido o nulo  espero que me puedan ayudar :)

gracias de antemano

Comment: Muestra como estas defines la variable en el archivo 1 y como intentas acceder a ella en el archivo 2.

Comment: imagino que en tu archivo html tienes algo como 
script archivo1.js
script archivo2.js 

si en archivo1.js tienes 
var algo = ""
function xxx() { algo = "ejemplo" } 
xxx() // cambio el valor algo 
y quieres acceder a la variable algo desde archivo2.js si se podria. 

Pero si tienes algo como esto en archivo1.js
function xxx() { var algo = "xxx" } 
xxx();
y quieres acceder a esa variable , no se va a poder por el scope donde esta declarado es interno. 

No se si este asi lo tengas declarado , muestra algo de código :D

Comment: Igual si tienes primero archivo2.js y luego archivo1.js igual no la va a encontrar.  Otra opcion ya que no sabemos como esta tu codigo, seria hacer esto window.varglobal = "valor que quiero obtener" y asi desde el otro script solo llamas a window.varglobal

Saludos

Comment: gracias por la ayuda...en efecto primero declaro mis variables y luego las funciones, podrias darme un ejemplo del windows.varglobal ese tal ves me sea util :)

Comment: El objeto window hace referencia a la ventana en la que te encuentras y además de que tiene sus métodos como window.alert, window.console, etc. Le podemos agregar propiedades, ejem: 
window.a = 2; 
window.b = "s";
// Si queremos obtener sus valores solo la invocamos
console.log(window.a) // 2
console.log(window.b) // "s"

Otra forma que podrías usar para pasar un valor seria guarda un valor en localstorage.

Comment: un pequeño detalle es que los dos scripts se ejecutan casi al mismo tiempo, tal ves  podría ser por eso,  ok investigare acerca del localstorage

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar **ECMAscript6** y La sentencia `import`, se usa para importar funciones que han sido exportadas desde un módulo externo. (osea variables también).

**Sintaxis**

```
 import defaultExport from "module-name";
 import * as name from "module-name";
 import { export } from "module-name";
 import { export as alias } from "module-name";
 import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
 import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
 import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name"; 
 import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
 import "module-name";
```

**Importa un solo miembro de un módulo.**

Dado un objeto o valor llamado myExport que ha sido exportado del módulo my-module ya sea implícitamente (porque todo el módulo ha sido exportado) o explícitamente (usando la sentencia export ), esto inserta myExport en el ámbito actual.

```
 import {myExport} from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Espero te ayude saludos.

> Nota: para usar import y que funcione en todos los navegadores puedes usar [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) y [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) ya que todavía no tiene soporte en todos los Navegadores

**Ejemplos**

Importar un archivo secundario para asistir en un procesamiento de una petición JSON AJAX.

**El módulo: file.js**

```
function getJSON(url, callback) {
 let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onload = function () { 
callback(this.responseText) 
 };
 xhr.open('GET', url, true);
 xhr.send();
 }

 export function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
  getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}
```

**El programa principal: main.js**

```
 import { getUsefulContents } from '/modules/file.js';

  getUsefulContents('http://www.example.com',
    data => { doSomethingUseful(data); });
```

**Fuente:** [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/import)